# MVC4 - refreshing partial view after deleting object with Ajax.ActionLink acting unexpectedly

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a DIV (`tenant-reference-photos`) that holds a partial view that display photos. Beside each photo is a delete button. When it's clicked, I want the photo to be removed from the list and only the DIV to be updated by Ajax.

I'm using an `Ajax.ActionLink` for the delete action:

```
<div>
    @Ajax.ActionLink("Delete", "DeleteReference",
    new { id = photo.ImageId },
    new AjaxOptions { InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, HttpMethod = "POST", 
                      UpdateTargetId = "tenant-reference-photos" },
    new { @class = "btn btn-primary" })
</div>
```

Controller actions:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult DeleteReference(int id)
{
    return View(refPhotoRepository.Find(id));
}

[HttpPost, ActionName("DeleteReference")]
public ActionResult DeleteReferenceConfirmed(int id)
{
    try
    {
        refPhotoRepository.Delete(id);
        refPhotoRepository.Save();
        return PartialView("_TenantReferencePhotosPartial");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
         // handle exception   
    }
    return View();
}
```

When I click delete, the action fires and record is deleted from the database. The problem is with `return PartialView("_TenantReferencePhotosPartial");`. When the action tries to return the partial, I get a NullReferenceException at `@if (Model.ReferencePhotos.Count == 0)`.

**_TenantReferencePhotosPartials.cshtml**

```
<div>
@if (Model.ReferencePhotos.Count == 0)
{
    <h3>You haven't uploaded any references! 
        @Ajax.ActionLink("Upload now?",
            "TenantUploadReference",
            new AjaxOptions
            {
                UpdateTargetId = "tenant-reference-photos",
                InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                HttpMethod = "GET",
                LoadingElementId = "ajax-loader"
            })</h3>
}
else
{
    foreach (var photo in Model.ReferencePhotos)
    {
    <ul class="thumbnails">
        <li class="span8">
            <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
                <img src="@Url.Action("GetReference", "Tenants", new { id = photo.ImageId })" alt="@photo.Name") />
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="span4 btn-group btn-group-vertical">
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" id="showEditPhotoModal" role="button" data-toggle="modal">Edit</a>
            @Ajax.ActionLink("Delete", "DeleteReference",
         new { id = photo.ImageId },
         new AjaxOptions { InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, HttpMethod = "POST", UpdateTargetId = "tenant-reference-photos" },
         new { @class = "btn btn-primary" })
        </li>
    </ul>
    }
}
</div>
```

Even if there are several photos in the collection and one is deleted, the exception is still thrown at the line mentioned previously. Some help would be appreciated.

Comment: where did you define this fuction? in the same .cshtml page or in _layout.cshtml page. Looks like it could not resolve on the page where you are referencing it.

Comment: I have it defined in file called site.js, when I view source it's there. I've had some trouble with jQuery $ not being defined in partials even though it's there in the source. If I resolve the not defined error, is my js function on the right track to refreshing the DIV?

Comment: are you seeing the source of site and jQuery javascript files or just the links to them in head section or at the bottom. Once you see the source of those files, you will find both of those errors are resolved. Right now, you are refreshing the whole page with - window.location.reload(true); To update div without page refresh - you just need to assign the incoming html to div like - ("#div_id").html(incoming_html);

Comment: What if you return the partial view ''with its corresponding model''?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do I resolve the above error?
>
> I've had some trouble with jQuery $ not being defined in partials even
>   though it's there in the source

I believe this is in connection with your problem. When I encounter this on a partial view, what always works for me is to include it in a `script section`. So on your `_Layout.cshtml` where you write your scripts you can add this:

```
// Do this after you referenced jquery
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
<script>
// some script references
</script>
```

Then on your view you do this:

```
@section scripts {
    $(function() {
        <script>
            function onDeleteReferenceSuccess(data, status, xhr) {
                if (data.error) { /* handle error */ }
                else {
                    window.location.reload(true);
                }
            }
        </script>
    });
}
```

> Once above is resolved, how do I update the only the DIV?
>   Since you deleted the item I would assume you would want to delete the div - that represents the item.

If my assumption is correct then why not give it an `Id` so you can delete it afterwards in your `else` statement:

```
else {
    // instead of this -> window.location.reload(true);
    $("#id_of_the_div").remove();
}
```

**UPDATE:**
Your updated question throws off my original answer. But let me include the updated answer here first (and then clean-up afterwards). So the reason you are having a null reference error is because you are not returning the model:

```
refPhotoRepository.Delete(id);
refPhotoRepository.Save();
// build the model here and pass it to the partial view
// this will most probably involve querying your data store again
var model = goBuildTheModel();
return PartialView("_TenantReferencePhotosPartial", model;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I should have mentioned in my question that there can be many photos displayed from a list, and there's a delete button beside each one (Ajax.ActionLink as per question) that takes photo.ImageId as parameter to be passed to the controller action. For this reason I'd like refresh the DIV, so any remaining photos will still be visible. So would I need to assign the incoming html to the DIV as per @Typist 's comment?

Comment: In a RESTful way of doing a delete, you should not return an html. A status (200 OK) will do. Besides you are not "getting" resources when doing a delete so why refresh the entire div? When you **should** only refresh the "line" that you deleted. That's the better approach of what you're doing. Oh and if your intention is to  make sure your user have the most fresh view then do a redirect or another GET and then refresh your div from that GET.

Comment: In my partial that displays photos, I first check if(list.count==0), if it is an Ajax.ActionLink is displayed to user that facilitates image uploading. The reason I'm trying the RESTful approach is because after a successful photo delete, when I redirect to an action that returns the photo partial, I'm getting a NullReferenceException at if(list.count == 0). This even happens if there's several photos in the list and I click delete on one. All getting a bit confusing...

Comment: But a DELETE on a RESTful approach should not return a view or an html for that matter. [See this reference](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.7).

Comment: I've updated my question with what I was trying to do originally. Appreciate if you could take another look.

Comment: Rookie error, sometimes it's the simple stuff that goes over my head when looking into things for so long. I presume by goBuildTheModel you mean get the latest 'version' of the collection?

Comment: Yes, that is right. You will most probably get it from the database.